# I am working in company name or at company name?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Please help me figure out this one.

> "I am working in [company name]"
>
> "I am working at [company name]"

Which one is correct? In or at?

Comment: Usually, when i refer to myself I use 'at' and for others I use 'in'. Like I am working at ABC pvt ltd. and he is working in XYZ solutions.

Comment: You can work "at" or "for" a company.  You work "in" a sector or profession.

Comment: Another possibility is *with*. For example, in many job ads, they will write *"Come work with us!*" However, some bosses seem to prefer you saying you work for them to you saying you work with them. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

I think...

> We work ***for*** some company as an employer 
>  We work ***in*** some department. 
>  We work ***at*** some location.

Said that...

I work for Infosys, in the content department at its corporate office.

Good point to remember as TRomano says...

> You work *in* some sector

So...

> I work *in* the IT industry

Note: "at" can also be used when the object is not a person, such as: "I work at Microsoft", "I work for Microsoft", "I work for John" anb "I work at John's company" instead of "I work at John" (Courtesy -dexgecko)

Comment: "at" can also be used when the object is not a person, such as: "I work at Microsoft", "I work for Microsoft", "I work for John" anb "I work at John's company" instead of "I work at John"

Answer (score 6):

> I am working **for** company_name.
>
> I am working **at** company_name.
>
> I am working **with** company_name.

Some nuances in meaning:

- ***in/at*** : to emphasize the physical place.
- "***with***": may not be an employee rather a freelancer/consultant/conntractor of some kind.

> I am working **in** a company (that manufactures android phones)

Comment: `+1` for *with* for contractors and partner companies. As a contractor, I always say *work with*.

Comment: With proper names, all those sentences in the first block should omit `a`.  Consider : `I am working for a Google` or `I am working at a Google` - these are wrong.  Rather : `I am working for Google` or `I am working at Google`.

Comment: @ J...duly edited

Comment: I disagree with your last example: you are working *for* the company that makes the phones, *in* their factory/office/wherever.