# "work for" / "work in" / "work at"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know what usually follows after each proposition in sentences with the word "work".

These are what I understand so far:

I work **for** my boss. ( usually for certain person )

I work **in** a accounting corporation. (usually for business area )

I work **at** Samsung. ( usually for specific name of company )

Could you please tell me if I understand rightly?

Comment: Useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58291/i-am-working-in-company-name-or-at-company-name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I work for my boss.*

This is OK grammatically, but feels odd to me because it seems rather tautological: by definition the person you work for is your boss, so there's no need to say so. It would be better to indicate the specific person who is your boss:

- I work for him
- I work for Amanda Jones
- I work for Dr Jenkins
- I work for the CEO *(you'd only say this if you report directly to the CEO)*

(Of course if you are self-employed, or unemployed, then you wouldn't be talking about working *for* somebody in the first place.)

> *I work in a accouting corporation. (usually for business area )*

You wouldn't say that you work *in* a corporation, you'd say *at* or *for* them. It is correct to say *in* when talking about which part of the company you work for, or if you are talking about a place. So:

- I work for an accounting company.
- I work at a famous legal firm.
- I work in the accounting department at Samsung.
- I work in the cafeteria.
- I work in London.
- I work for Samsung in London.

(Also, note that it's *an* accounting corporation, not *a* accounting corporation.)

> *I work at Samsung.*

This is correct. It would also be correct to say I work *for* Samsung.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i have one question. Per what you said, "work at" can be replaced by"work for" , and vise versa. So there is no difference at all between the two? For example, " I work for an accounting company." / " I work at an accounting company." They are exactly the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, both mean the same thing when talking about the organisation where you work.

Comment: *It is correct to say in when talking about which part of the company you work for...* hmm so what about *"I work **in** an IT company'* or it should take ***'for'***

Comment: @MaulikV - That should be *for* or *at*. As per the example in my answer *I work for an accounting company.* You can say more generally *I work in IT.* (IT is the field/profession in which you work, but "an IT company" refers to a specific entity, even though you haven't named it.)